# Fourier Coefficients of Sawtooth Wave

Tags: fourier-transform

Following this [link](https://matrixlab-examples.com/fourier-series.html), we can see that the magnitude of the $n^{th}$ harmonic of a sawtooth wave is equal to:

$$
V_n = \frac{Vpp}{(n*\pi)}
$$

Converting that Matlab code (the code at the end of the page, not the first one) to Python, I got this:

```
from scipy import signal
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate data
dt = 0.01 # Sampling period
x = np.arange(0, 6 * np.pi+dt, dt)
vpp = 2
y = signal.sawtooth(x)
N = len(y) # Numer of points in the singal
T = 2*np.pi # Period
df = 1/T # Fundamental frequency

# Create the first subplot for the sawtooth wave
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Sawtooth wave')

# Generate harmonic frequencies
n = np.arange(1, 8)
v = vpp / (n * np.pi)

# Create the second subplot for the first harmonics
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.stem(n, v)
plt.xlabel('First harmonics')
plt.show()
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Now, using `fft` at the same `y` array:

```
# Fourier Coeficients
fourier_coef = fft(y)
fourier_coef = fourier_coef[1:8]
fourier_coef = np.abs(fourier_coef)

# Plot
plt.stem(n, fourier_coef)
plt.xlabel('First harmonics')
```

This is the result:

[image]

Why are those magnitudes from `v`and `fourier_coef` different?

Comment: Because you’re looking at the first Fourier coefficients, not the **harmonics**

Comment: @Jdip isn't the magnitude of a harmonic the same thing as the magnitude of a Fourier Coefficient?

Comment: Yes but the first $n$ harmonics don't map to the first $n$ Fourier coefficients! You're looking at the values of the first $8$ Fourier coefficients. In the spectrum, the harmonics are located at frequencies that are multiples of the fundamental frequency. What you're looking at are just the first $8$ coefficients representing the first $8$ frequencies of your signal, **not the first $8$ harmonics**.

Comment: @Jdip The first value of `fourier_coef` is the DC component. Isn't the second value the magnitude at the fundamental frequency (or, the first harmonic)? The third value the magnitude at 2x fundamental frequency (second harmonic), etc? Check my edit if you can please.

Comment: The second value is not necessarily the fundamental frequency, no. How familiar are you with the Fourier Transform?

Comment: @Jdip Not very familiar, just started into it and was under the impression that the second value from the `fft` function of `scipy` was the one at the fundamental frequency, and the others are just multiples of it (and they indeed are). But, why that second value is not the fundamental frequency value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151717/discussion-between-murilo-and-jdip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in the comments, the first $n$ harmonics don't map to the first $n$ Fourier coefficients. If you don't see why, you really need to go back to the basics of the Fourier Transform.

As far as seeing the harmonics using the Fourier Transform, here is a snippet that will help you:

```py
# Fourier Coeficients
fourier_coef = fft(y)
fourier_coef = 2*fourier_coef/N #scale
fourier_coef = np.abs(fourier_coef)

freqVector = fftfreq(N,dt)
plt.stem(freqVector[0:30], fourier_coef[0:30])
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
```

Here you see that the harmonics identified by Fourier Transform match those calculated with $$
V_n = \frac{Vpp}{(n*\pi)}
$$

[image]